# Search the public stream in Facebook

Tags: facebook, stream

Is there any change i can search for anything in the Open Stream in Facebook?

Let´s say that i want to look for "obama", this will return all of the obama mentions for a bunch of people in their streams, so far I haven't found anything like this, probably only looking in one user stream, but not the whole stuff.

So, i haven't found a way to do this, but how come, sites like socialmention.com can do it? Do they query user by user streams? and how to do it without users permissions?

What do you guys think?

Thanks in advance!

Camilo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just found the solution, you can find it here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#search

Thanks for the help!

Camilo

Comment: You can use the following example:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=STACK%20OVERFLOW&type=post

Comment: This is returning that have both stack and overflow, not necessarily "stack overflow". Is this expected? What if I dont want this behaviour?

Comment: The search endpoint is deprecated (April 30th, 2015) and will only work on v1 of the Graph API.